# How to setup environment variables in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, environment-variables

I have been using a .env file to run my app in my local machine. However when deploying my app using aws ec2 instance, I am at a complete loss on how to set up the ENV vars as I am a complete beginner at using AWS. Please help me to set up the environment variables.

Comment: Why not use `.env` on instance as well?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was thinking too much

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments.

Since `.env` is used on local workstation successfully, it can also be used on ec2 instance.

Just have to be careful with not string any **sensitive information** in `.env` and using public repositories, as you may leak your passwords or access keys.

For **storing secrets at AWS**, the recommended way would be through [secret manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/) or [ssm parameter store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html). Also any permissions that your app may require to access these or other AWS services should be provided through [instance role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html), not by hard codding AWS credentials into app or instance.

Comment: Since the variables defined in the .env should not be committed (are ignored) into the repository, because it's senstive information, there should be some other way to define the environment variables. I am also stuck at this. I found this link and I have added my variables to the `bashrc` file in the ubuntu server, but I can't find a way so that the app knows how to get them. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/env-vars.html

Comment: @ivandax You don't store secrets nor any sensitive info there. I think its clear from my answer?